# Does anyone recognize this function for the Hubble value as a function of density?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I'm trying to reverse engineer a C++ package I found for computing the power spectrum of CMB (EasyCMB).  There's a formula that appears to be calculating the Hubble value at a given scale factor, **a**, but I don't recognize it.  Does anyone recognize this and can anyone explain how/if it works:

$$H(a)=a\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}(\rho_\gamma(a)+\rho_m(a)+\rho_\nu(a)+\rho_\lambda)}\sqrt{\frac{8 \pi G}{\hbar c}}$$
$\rho_\gamma$ is the radiation density, $\rho_m$ is the matter density, $\rho_\nu$ appears to be the (massless) neutrino density, and $\rho_\lambda$ is the dark energy density (constant).

I'm familiar with this function for critical density:
$$\rho_c=\frac{3H^2}{8\pi G}$$Rearranging we get:
$$H=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\rho_c 8 \pi G}$$
so I think we're close, but I don't see how the factors **a**, $\hbar$, and **c** get involved.

Comment: Could this be related with Dirac's large number hypothesis?

Comment: By using Friedmann Equation, we can write. $H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3} \sum \rho_i - \frac{kc^2}{a^2}$ for $k=0$ and by taking different density components we can write, 
$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}(\rho_\gamma(a)+\rho_m(a)+\rho_\nu(a)+\rho_\lambda)$.
So $H = \sqrt{\frac{8\pi G}{3}(\rho_\gamma(a)+\rho_m(a)+\rho_\nu(a)+\rho_\lambda)}$. 
I noticed that $\sqrt{\frac{8 \pi G}{\hbar c}}$ is the $\frac{1}{M_p}$ where $M_p$ is the plack mass. So I dont know where the extra terms $(a, \sqrt{\hbar c})$ comes from.

Comment: @Reign - Post that as an answer and I'll upvote it.  Still not sure how the **a** factors into it, but I think the author is assuming $\hbar=c=1$.  The code looks sloppy when it comes to $c$ & $\hbar$.

Comment: @Quarkly Its okay if that helps you. I am feeling lazy to write it again :p. Its really interesting that theres extra scale factor in front of the equation.